# What do apple docs mean when they say local receipt validation does not "Includes additional subscription information"?

Tags: ios, storekit, receipt-validation

Apple docs on validating receipts [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique) say that verifying locally will not "Include additional subscription information" as compared to verifying on server. I am wondering what is entailed by this? In particular, for my purposes I need to access the [Subscription Trial Period](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html) field mentioned here, and I'm wondering if that is precluded from local receipt validation?